# Como mudar o tamanho da fonte de todas as páginas usando o Range do ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic3, angularjs-directives

Tenho o seguinte código html [settings.html]

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-range min="1" max="4" step="1" snaps="true" [(ngModel)]="saturation" color="grey">
         <ion-label range-left style="font-size: 12px;">A</ion-label>
         <ion-label range-right style="font-size: 20px;">A</ion-label>
    </ion-range>
</ion-item>
```

Com fazer para alterar o tamanho da fonte de todas as páginas dinamicamente no arquivo settings.ts ao arrastar o range?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um evento que emita a variavel para todas as paginas que forem sendo acessadas. algo mais ou menos assim:
no app.compoenent

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public events: Events) {}

function changeFont(font) {
  events.publish('font:change', font);
}
```

Depois no seu compoenent você coloca

```
public font:any;
    events.subscribe('font:change', (font) => {
       this.font = font
    });
```

e na sua view de template pode ser no body, content o que englobar todo o projeto você coloca

```
style="font-size:{font}px"
```

com adaptações para o seu projeto, deve funcionar

Comment: Boa !! Valeu, cara.